# Populate fieldlist from GET request?

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms

I have a form that accepts a list of strings :

```
class MyForm(Form):
    __orders__ = None
    order_by = FieldList(StringField('order_by'))
```

And here's my view :

```
@app.route("/")
def my_view():
    form = MyForm(request.args)
    print form.order_by.entries
```

I tried to request the url with :

```
/?order_by=hello&order_by=world
/?order_by[]=hello&order_by[]=world
/?order_by%5B%5D=hello&order_by%5B%5D=world
```

`form.order_by.entries` is always empty (`[]`)

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here's how I did, using SelectMultipleField, but without having to deal with choices :

```
class MultipleTextField(SelectMultipleField):
    """
    No different from a normal select field, except this one can take (and
    validate) multiple choices.  You'll need to specify the HTML `rows`
    attribute to the select field when rendering.
    """
    widget = widgets.Select(multiple=True)
    coerce = str
    choices = []

    def pre_validate(self, form):
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but looking at the source code it seems this might work:

```
/?order_by-0=hello&order_by-1=world
```

Comment: Imagine the following : `jQuery.param({'order_by': ['hello', 'world']}, true);`, this wouldn't work. I would have to implement a non logicial param that would respect what the server expect. Not KISS at all.

Comment: I'm really surprised there is no basic implementation of either param[] or param=x&param=y in WTForms! It's the base of param sending to the server. Why implement their own ?!